# Discord.py add delay to bot response

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, delay

I am using an on_message function in discord.py and after recieving the message the bot responds: await message.channel.send("response")
but this happens instantly, is there any way for me to delay this reponse for a couple of seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`await asyncio.sleep(seconds_to_sleep)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=sleep#asyncio.sleep) which adds async-friendly delay to your bot actions

```py
import asyncio

# ... then in a cog
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message):
        if message.author == self.bot.user:
            return
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await message.channel.send("response")
```